# Manipulating a helper of a crispy form in a view

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

just started working with crispy forms in Django and so far it is awesome! I am however stuck with the following problem:

Whenever I try to Manipulate my helper in my view, as explained here: https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/tags.html , I get the following TypeError: 'ContactForm' object is not callable.

**forms.py**

```
  1 from django import forms                                                        
  2 from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, reverse_lazy                      
  3 from .models import Contact                                                     
  4 from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _                         
  5                                                                                 
  6 from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper                                      
  7 from crispy_forms.layout import Submit                                          
  8                                                                                 
  9                                                                                 
 10 class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):                                             
 11                                                                                 
 12     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):                                        
 13         self.helper = FormHelper()                                              
 14         self.helper.add_input(Submit('add_contact', 'Add contact'))
 15         self.helper.show_errors = True                                          
 16         self.helper.form_action = reverse_lazy('contacts:create_contact')                                      
 17         super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)                      
 18                                                                                 
 19     class Meta:                                                                  
 20         model = Contact                                                         
 21         fields = ['title']
```

**views.py**

```
  2 from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals                        
  3                                                                                 
  4 from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, reverse_lazy                      
  5 from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView, RedirectView, UpdateView, FormView
  6 from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView                                
  7 from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required                       
  8 from django.shortcuts import render                                             
  9                                                                                 
 10 from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin                                     
 11 from .forms import ContactForm                                                  
 12 from .models import Contact                                                                                  
 13                                                                                                              
 14                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 20 class CreateContactView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):                                                     
 21     template_name = 'contacts/contact_form.html'                                
 22     form_class = ContactForm()  
 23     form_class.helper.form_action = ""                                                                              
 23     model = Contact                                                             
 24     success_url = reverse_lazy('contacts:list_contacts')
```

Do you guys know what I am doing wrong? How can I make this form callable? Obviously the error starts at line 22 of my view, I can solve it by removing line 23 and removing the brackets at line 22, but I have to do this if I want to change helper.form_action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `form_class` in a class based view, you must use the *class*, not an *instance* of it.

```
class CreateContactView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):                                                     
    template_name = 'contacts/contact_form.html'                                
    form_class = ContactForm
```

This code is loaded once, when the server starts.

If you want to change the helper, then you need to edit the form instance in a method of the view. This code is run once for every request. For example, you could override [`get_form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form).

```
class CreateContactView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):                                                     
    template_name = 'contacts/contact_form.html'                                
    form_class = ContactForm

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super(CreateContactView, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.helper.form_action = ""
        return form
```

However, for the example you have given it would be easier to set the action in the form's `__init__` method. Then you won't have to override the `get_form` method as well.

```
 class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):                                             

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):                                        
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_action = ""                                                                              
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `form_class` definition of your `CreateContactView`. You don't have to instantiate it (i.e. `ContactForm()`) when using Class-based Views. You need to change it to:

```
class CreateContactView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):                                                     
    template_name = 'contacts/contact_form.html'                                
    form_class = ContactForm 
    form_class.helper.form_action = ""                                                                              
    model = Contact                                                             
    success_url = reverse_lazy('contacts:list_contacts')
```

Comment: That wouldn't work because then you get the error ContactForm has no attribute 'helper'.